# ImportError: /path/pyexpat.so not defined in file libexpat.so.0

Tags: python

I am getting this error when trying to run a classic python code written by x-colleagues.

Can u anyone help me out with solving this issue. I have googled throughly and couldn't find any solution.

`Python version  : 2.4.3`

`ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so: symbol XML_SetHashSalt, version EXPAT_1_95_8_RH not defined in file libexpat.so.0 with link time reference`

Comment: Was this python copied from another machine?

Comment: Python was already installed on the machine(CentOS 5). The python script I was trying run was from a different machine.

Comment: try doing "yum upgrade" then, that might fix it.

Comment: Thanks Keith. But I am afraid that upgrading might mess up some other dependencies. Also it seems like Centos 5 needs the python version 2.4.3 as a dependency(reed some where on the google). Is there any other way around. The interesting thing is the other server where I copied the code also had the same version of the Python but a different build version. Would it make any difference.

Comment: CentOS is supposed to be a stable distro. THat means that upgrades should not break anything. It looks like someone has placed a different Python there than CentOS provides. Upgrading might put the "proper" one back in.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and the root cause for me is that i built libexpat myself from source but pyexpat.so seems to depand on RH customized libexpat version.

So check your dependencies with:

```
ldd /usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so
```

Then check your libexpat.so file. If possible, you can try to re-install the rpm of expat-devel.x86_64 (for 64 bit).

```
yum install expat-devel.x86_64
```

Comment: It might not work with python3 but at least it gives good direction. I had similar issue. So I added the path of the pyexpat.so which was at a different location and it worked out.

Comment: For python 3.6 i added this question  as i am facing different type of problems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414448/pip3-throws-undefined-symbol-xml-sethashsalt. Please could you help here or in the mentioned question.