# Why I got undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt error when I run code from PHP, but not when I run from terminal?

Tags: php, json, python-3.x, xml, apache

I have a python code which use an `.xml` and search in it, and I can perfectly run it from terminal, but can't from my PHP site. I got `python3: symbol lookup error: python3: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt` in `error_log` file when I did it.

This is my python code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import os.path, time
import datetime
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys
import json 

#update the db if it is older than a month
today = datetime.datetime.today()
modified_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime('database.xml'))
duration = today - modified_date
if duration.days > 30: 
    os.remove('database.xml') 

    url = 'https://sourceOfDatabase.xml'
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    open('database.xml', 'wb').write(r.content)

tree = ET.parse('database.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


searchterm = sys.argv[1]

out = []

error = 0
status = 0
nrOfResults = 0


for channel in root:
    for item in channel:
        tmp = []
        match = 0
        for child in item:
            tmp.append(child.text)          
            if (child.text.lower().find(searchterm.lower()) != -1):
                nrOfResults = nrOfResults +1    
                match = 1
        if match == 1:
            out.append(tmp)
out.append(status)
out.append(nrOfResults)

print(json.dumps(out))
```

This is my php code:

```php
<?php 
$test = 'searchterm';
$command = escapeshellcmd('python3 academic_search.py'); 
$output = shell_exec($command);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $output;
?>
```

How can I run this from php?

Comment: Your PHP has a missing `');` on line 3

Comment: Your problem is most likely down to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable value for PHP's shell. Does this answer your question? [pip3 throws undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63414448/283366)

Comment: @Phil sorry, that was a copy paste error from the IDE

Comment: @Phil I see that question before, but no, that didn't helped me, I didn't got any error from pip

Comment: It's not about pip, it's about environmental configuration. Take some time to actually look at the answers

Comment: I've seen this link too https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2094005 but I don't know how to do this, I'm not an ubuntu expert, so I  don't know if there is a library conflict or not, but it is strange because I didn't installed any library before this error.

Comment: Try `$command = 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH python3 academic_search.py';`

Comment: Thank you this worked! Please answer it and I can accept it